# SolidWorks URDF exporter incorrect link masses

Tags: ros, sw-urdf-exporter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I can tell, there seems to be an issue with the SW->URDF converter which causes the mass of every link to be set to the mass of the entire assembly, rather than that single link. For example, I can create a robot composed of two rectangular links, one of length 1m and expected mass 10kg and one of length 0.5m and expected mass 5kg. When the exporter runs, it assigns a mass of 15kg to both links. Am I misinterpreting the expected behavior?

I've also noticed that looking carefully at the video on the Willow Garage blog here: http://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2012/10/18/exporting-urdfs-directly-solidworks (at around 59s) that the demo appears to have the same behavior I observed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47226/solidworks-urdf-exporter-incorrect-link-masses/) by [rdeits](https://answers.ros.org/users/3164/rdeits/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, sorry for the delay in answering this question. This was addressed in version V1.0 Build 4714.35040 (released much later than the posting of this question).

For future reference, issues with this tool should be reported on the [issue tracker](https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/sw_urdf_exporter_trac) for this project.

---

Originally posted by [brawner](https://answers.ros.org/users/2146/brawner/) with karma: 581 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1